# How to show contextual links buttons in templates with minimal markup?

Tags: 8, navigation

I want to get rid of the most markup in Drupal 8 templates, but still want to have working contextual links. How to do this?

Answer (score 11):

In Drupal 8 the contextual links markup is still printed via the {{ title_suffix }} variable (D7: print render($title_suffix);).

block.html.twig (default):

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'block',
    'block-' ~ configuration.provider|clean_class,
  ]
%}
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  {{ title_prefix }}
  {% if label %}
    <h2{{ title_attributes }}>{{ label }}</h2>
  {% endif %}
  {{ title_suffix }}
  {% block content %}
    {{ content }}
  {% endblock %}
</div>
```

So a minimal version would still work:

```
{{ title_suffix }}
{{ content) }}
```

Printed result for user without the permission "Use contextual links"

```
<div data-contextual-id="block:block=foo:|block_content:block_content=1:changed=1423224125"></div>
BlaBlaBlaContent
```

Printed result for user with the permission "Use contextual links"

```
<div data-contextual-id="block:block=foo:|block_content:block_content=1:changed=1423224125" class="contextual-render-processed contextual" role="form">
    <button type="button" class="trigger focusable visually-hidden" aria-pressed="false">Open configuration options</button>
    <ul hidden="" class="contextual-links">
        <li class="block-configure"><a href="/admin/structure/block/manage/foo?destination=node/4">Configure block</a></li>
        <li class="block-contentblock-edit"><a href="/block/4?destination=node/4">Edit</a></li>
        <li class="block-contentblock-delete"><a href="/block/4/delete?destination=node/4">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
BlaBlaBlaContent
```

The default formatting will be destroyed because the outer class .contextual-region is missing and it's defined like this in contextual.theme.css:

```
.contextual-region .contextual .contextual-links {...}
.contextual-region .contextual .contextual-links li {...}
...
```

So you have to overwrite (https://www.drupal.org/node/1876600) this file or copy the definitions in one of your theme css files and change for example like:

```
.contextual-region .contextual .contextual-links, .contextual .contextual-links {...}
.contextual-region .contextual .contextual-links li, .contextual .contextual-links li {...}
```

Or you place manually in the template or via JS ".contextual-region" into an outer dom element or print {{ attributes }} there.

Printed result:

```
<div class="block block--classic contextual-region">
    <div data-contextual-id="block:block=foo:|block_content:block_content=5:changed=1423308445" class="contextual-render-processed contextual" role="form">
        <button type="button" class="trigger focusable" aria-pressed="false">Open configuration options</button>
        <ul hidden="" class="contextual-links">
            <li class="block-configure"><a href="/admin/structure/block/manage/callforproposalsblock?destination=node/4">Configure block</a></li><li class="block-contentblock-edit"><a href="/block/5?destination=node/4">Edit</a></li>
            <li class="block-contentblock-delete"><a href="/block/5/delete?destination=node/4">Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    BlaBlaBlaContent
</div>
```

Remark: Without the upper .contextual-region the mouseover visibility of the contextual links icon is not working ...

Note: Current version of Drupal 8 is Beta 6 - so things may still change!

Comment: Just mentioning that this still works with D8 being out of beta status.